# MobileBardodeScanner fails to scan QRCode untill restarted after giving Camera Permissions

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, zxing.net

I'm trying to scan a QR Code from my Xamarin.Forms application but the QR Code isn't getting detected until i restart the scanner.

I'm using ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms. Once the `ScannerPage` has been pushed on the navigation stack it requests the camera permissions. After fulfilling the request it has access to the camera but isn't scanning the QR Code. I tried changing the permission handler since it works after restarting the scanner after granting the permission, but that didn't work.

```cs
        private async void createScanPageAsync()
        {
        #if __ANDROID__
        // Initialize the scanner first so it can track the current context
        MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize (Application);
        #endif
            var options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions()
            {
                TryHarder = true,
            };
            var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage()
            {
                Title = AppResources.scanPageTitle,
                DefaultOverlayTopText = AppResources.scanPageTitle,
                DefaultOverlayShowFlashButton = true
            };
            await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);


            scanPage.OnScanResult += (scanResult) =>
            {
                scanPage.IsScanning = false;
                Vibration.Vibrate();
                QRCode scans = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QRCode>(scanResult.Text);
                AppPreferences.Network.Ip = scans.ip;
                AppPreferences.Network.Port = scans.port;

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await Navigation.PopAsync();
                });
            };
        }
}
```

The expected outcome would be a successful scan on the first try, but i only get a successful scan after granting permissions and then reopening the scanner page.

Comment: have you tried requesting permission before you launch the scanner page?

Comment: I tried requesting it with the Plugin.Permissions NuGet package but the documentation is really outdated and it didn't really work out.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo so that others could help you better?

Answer (score 0):

For me the Xamarin.Essentials did the trick. It has a permission plugin that can help you ask for permission and after that, you can then launch the scanner without problem